# Unexpected token user = await User.create(user) when i try to create a new user

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I'm trying to create a new user using **node.js/adonis**

I create this two functions:

```
const User = use("App/Models/User")

async store ({ request, auth }){

    let user = new User()
    user = request.all()

    this.userLogged(auth).then(res => { 
        user.user_id = res.id
        console.log(user)
        user = await User.create(user)
        const token = await auth.generate(user)
        Object.assign(user, token)
        return user
    })
}

async userLogged(auth) {
    try {
        return await auth.getUser()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

The function "`userLogged()`" return the user that i receive the token in the authorization header.

So i try:

```
create a new instance of User;
put the request data in this instance;
take the user_id of the authorization header and put in the user.user_id;
create the user with the user_id;
take the token of the registred user;
put in the object user the token;
return the user;
```

but i'm receiving:

> Unexpected token user = await User.create(user)

Comment: Why do you keep reassigning different values to `user`?  Your code assigns to `user` or a property of `user` four separate times.   For example, `let user = new User()` then immediately followed by `user = request.all()` makes no sense at all as the first assignment to `user` is just overwritten and never used.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, i remove the user = new User()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to `await` something not in an `async` function, specifically the callback in your promise resolver `.then`.

```js
async store ({ request, auth }){

    let user = new User()
    user = request.all()

    this.userLogged(auth).then(async res => { 
        user.user_id = res.id
        console.log(user)
        user = await User.create(user)
        const token = await auth.generate(user)
        Object.assign(user, token)
        return user
    })
}
```

Also, based on the code provided, `store` does not need to be async since you're not `await`ing anything at the top level of its scope.

Comment: the user is being created but i'm not receiving the user return, i'm receiving: 204 status - No content

Comment: That's a different issue, and though I've not used Adonis, it seems you might need to include your response object and return a value to it. 
`store ({ request, auth, response }){ return response.json(someValue); }`

Comment: I make this way:

    store ({ request, auth }){

        let user = request.all()

        const response = this.usuarioLogado(auth).then(async res => { 
            user.user_id = res.id
            user = await User.create(user)
            const token = await auth.generate(user)
            Object.assign(user, token)
            return user
        })
        return response
    }

thanks for the attention